# Virtual PC doesnot meet SQL Server 2005 enterprise's hardware requirements?

Tags: sql-server, virtualization, hardware

I used Virtual PC to create a virtual machine with configuration:

CPU: Intel Pentium E6300 2.8Ghz overclocked to 3.66Ghz (which supports VT technology)

RAM: 600MB

I thought it was enough for me to install SQL Server 2005 enterprise on it. But installer still tells me that the virtual machine does not meet the hardware requirements. Did I forgot something about this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to install the 32 or 64 bit version.  Microsoft Virtual PC only supports a 32 bit virtual OS.
For reference here are the system requirements for SQL 2005.
http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/system-requirements.aspx

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I used 32-bit version. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Did I forgot something about this?

You didn't. It is not a supported configuration, hence the warning.

It should run OK, but I would avoid this for anything other than development/test (in which case developer edition would be simpler).

Check the MS web site for what virtualisation solutions are supported with SQL Server (and other server software).

Comment: after increasing the memory of the virtual machine to 1024MB, the warning's gone :). What a miracle!

Comment: It will work, just not fast with 512MB (as I did for ~18months).